# How to migrate code from TFS 2012 to Visual Studio team services?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

We are planning to migrate from tfs 2012 to VSTS, wanted to check if there is any method that can be used to migrate the source code that is in in TFS to VSTS (either GIT or TFVC)?

Many Thanks,

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO, have  read of the MS Docs [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-overview). SO is better for more specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility).